# Sonarqube.project.properties file not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

I have a simple C# Hello World project which I am trying to do Code Quality analysis with SonarQube.

`dotnet C:\git\itergo\sonar\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.7.1.2311-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end` throws an error.

> sonar-project.properties files are not understood by the SonarScanner for MSBuild. Remove those files from the following folders: C:\git\sonar_test\samples\core\console-apps\HelloMsBuild
>   09:24:17.089  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the SonarScanner for MSBuild either on the command line or in the `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` XML settings file as described in the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/).

Answer (score 1):

Now, the properties are added via ItemGroup in each .csproj file, this way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.cpd.exclusions">
    <Value>Models/**/*.cs</Value>
  </SonarQubeSetting>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `sonar-project.properties` file suitable to your project in your **project directory.**
If you don't place this file, it refers to the global configurations set in  `sonar-project.properties` file in the root folder.